# Dev- C++ Compiler Issues

Tags: dev-c++

A little forward, I have to use dev-c++ for my course at university and it must compile within it.

I have a program that I got working using multiple linked files, a header, a cpp, and  a main, and it will run but if I ever rebuild it it seems to drop the .cpp file saying that my class isn't a data type or has not been defined. Any insights as to why this is happening? Thanks for any help.

Comment: My first thought, and this is vague recollections from about ten years ago, is did you create a project, or are you just hitting "run" while looking at one of the code files?

Comment: and they are properly linked using #include and uses header gaurds.

Comment: At this point, we really need sample code so we can attempt to reproduce it.